# How to add a link preview in mattermost?

Tags: mattermost

How to add a link preview feature in mattermost ?

When a post containing a link is added, i'd like mattermost to automatically add a preview of the link content

Comment: It's now supported, please change accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be enabled with https://docs.mattermost.com/administration/config-settings.html#enable-link-previews

---

<strike>Not possible.</strike>

Feature request is here: https://mattermost.atlassian.net/browse/PLT-1835

Comment: Please revise answer, it's now supported

Comment: @CraigRinger Updated answer. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://docs.mattermost.com/administration/config-settings.html#enable-link-previews):

> This feature’s `config.json`
>   setting is `"EnableLinkPreviews": false` with options `true` and `false`

See below for details

> #### Enable Link Previews
>
> **True**: Enables users to display a preview of website content below the
>   message, if available. When true, website previews can be enabled from
>   Account Settings > Display > Website Link Previews.
>
> **False**: Website link previews are disabled.